# How to do DataTrigger Binding inside Validation.ErrorTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a `CustomControl` surrounded by a `ControlTemplate`. The `CustomControl` contains another `CustomControl` with `Label`, `TextBox` and `Validation.ErrorTemplate` for the `TextBox`.

What I am trying to do is, when I hover the `CustomControl` or focus the `TextBox` then the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` should popup.

For now it just pops up the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` if and only if I hover the `Border` around the `TextBox`. To be honest, I am not sure whether it is the `Border` from the `StackPanel` or `AdornedElementPlaceholder`. I really have no idea how to bind the `DataTrigger` inside the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` to outer `Border` `IsMouseOver` property or to the `IsFocused` property from `TextBox`.

Below the code I have so far:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomControl}" x:Key="CustomTemplate">
<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="outerBorder">
    <my:LabelControl Label="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Label}">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="3 0 3 0" Foreground="{DynamicResource Control.Foreground}">
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Resources>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="ViewModel.Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"/>
            </TextBox.Text>
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Triggers>
                    ...
                </Triggers>
            </TextBox.Style>
            <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="BorderBorder">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"  CornerRadius="3">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"/>
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=BorderBorder, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter  Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        </TextBox>
    </my:LabelControl>
</Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So the `DataTrigger` inside `Validation.ErrorTemplate` should be bound to `ElementName=outerBorder` if that is possible at all.

I guess the problem is that I have a `ControlTemplate` inside a `ControlTemplate` so the `DataTrigger` `Binding` in the inner `ControlTemplate` (`Validation.ErrorTemplate`) has no knowledge about the `Properties` of the outer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `Tag` property of the `TextBox` to the `IsMouseOver` property of the control itself, and then bind the `DataTrigger` to the `Tag` property of the adorned element:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomControl}" x:Key="CustomTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="outerBorder">
        <my:LabelControl Label="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ViewModel.Label}">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="3 0 3 0" Foreground="{DynamicResource Control.Foreground}"
                     Tag="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=my:CustomControl}}">
                <TextBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Resources>
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="ViewModel.Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"/>
                </TextBox.Text>
                <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="BorderBorder">
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"  CornerRadius="3">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"/>
                                <Border.Style>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AdornedElement.(TextBox.Tag), ElementName=textBox}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter  Property="Border.Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Border.Style>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            </TextBox>
        </my:LabelControl>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: woow thanks, worked like a charm ... can you explain `AdornedElement.(TextBox.Tag)` a bit please? and when I want a `DataTrigger` for `TextBox.IsFocused` too. Can I just set two `Tag` properties or how would that look like?

Comment: There is only one Tag property but you can bind to any property of the TextBox, e.g. `AdornedElement.(TextBox.IsFocused)`

Comment: do you have any advise how to achieve same behavior on DatePickerTextBox IsFocused? tried it the same way as you suggested but I dont know how to get the focus state of the DatePickerTextBox

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have Another issue. Please also remember to include a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve